# Shortcut to left align objects in PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office

I would like to know the shortcut to left align selected objects in PowerPoint Mac. Some web pages show that it is `alt+1`, but I don't think it works.

By the way, I have a [french keyboard](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC184F/B/apple-wireless-keyboard-french).

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark as I don't use Powerpoint for Mac, but try these and report back which one works (if at all):

- Command + L
- Command + Shift + ] (Command + })

Comment: `Command + L` doesn't left align objects; As I have a french keyboard, there is no `]` or `}` key (there is `)` key)...